# how to troubleshoot DRF router duplicate urls

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to set a series of Django Rest Framework URLs.

Below is my Serializer/ViewSet makeup

```
class ModelSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    schemas = SchemaSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = dbModels
        fields = ('ModelName', 'pk', 'schemas')

class ModelViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = dbModels.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ModelSerializer

class ModelListSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = dbModels
        fields = ('ModelName', 'pk')

class ModelListViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = dbModels.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ModelListSerializer
```

Here is my Router List:
from datagenerator.serializer import UserViewSet, \
    ModelViewSet, ModelListViewSet

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'models', ModelViewSet)
router.register(r'modellist', ModelListViewSet)
```

However, when I'm running The localhost webserver, the DRF Front end shows this:

```
"models": "http://localhost:8000/datamaker/api/modellist/",
"modellist": "http://localhost:8000/datamaker/api/modellist/",
```

How do I stop this?
I need models to go to models and modellist to go to modellist.

Thanks much...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the [`base_name`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/) argument:

```
router.register(r'models', ModelViewSet, base_name='models')
router.register(r'modellist', ModelListViewSet, base_name='modellist')
```

Since your serializers share the same data model, DRF might get stuck trying to automatically discover the url naming pattern. So it's better in this case to explicitly set the `base_name`.

If you're using a newer version of Django Rest Framework, you'll need to use `basename='models'` instead of `base_name='model'`.

Comment: ok.  The DRF is still confused.  The URLs are good, but they are both running to the models API.  What else am I missing?  Thanks.

Comment: Did you restart your server? Things should work now.

Comment: yes.  DRF still confused.  Right now, both links are good, but when you click on the links, they go to the same API.

Comment: Maybe your `SchemaSerializer` just doesn't work, so the output is the same for both serializers?

Comment: Yes. Individually they work, but if I add both, DRF goes bonkers.  The option here is whether or not to get the child objects with the output.  In some cases, I don't want to load the whole thing with children, so I just want a roster of models.  In other cases, I want a model with all children, grandkids, etc....